# Are the different quantum interpretations mere differences in Semantics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations

Are the different interpretations of quantum mechanics mere semantic differences?(since almost all the interpretations share the same mathematical formalism , except for the collapse models).
Does the future developments in theoretical physics depend on the interpretation we prescribe to?

Answer (score 1):

As far as they make the same predictions, the different interpretations play two roles. The first, main role, seems to be to provide psychological comfort to the person whose thinking resonates with that interpretation.

However, it is possible that a particular interpretation drives research for possible future extensions of QM. Not many people are working in this area although there are isolated papers now and then. Part of the reason for the lack of interest is that all experimental data agree very well with the current QM, and whatever discomfort someone feels with some interpretation can usually be dismissed by adopting a different interpretation.

Still, some people are looking not for different interpretations of existing QM, but rather seeking a different set of axioms to motivate the current QM. To some, the current axioms do not seem very "physically" motivated compared to eg the postulates of special relativity.

See eg. this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205039) for a recent perspective of one practitioner on the state of the field.